# Reciprocal of 81 being the sequence of all natural numbers?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, natural-numbers, quadratic-reciprocity

According to this document: http://www.answering-christianity.com/fakir60/81.htm describing the theory of scientist Peter Plichta, the `reciprocal` of **81** is: ***the sequence of all natural numbers*** (*0.01234567890...*).

Myself not quite being a mathematician, but still trying to reproduce everything I come across, typed it in the calculator: `reciproc(81)`. And there it was:

> 0.0123456790...

Uuhm, `8` where art thou?

The missing `8` is accounted for in the document as it goes on describing it is merely an illusion because the reciprocal calculation should be written differently and it should be read as `Gauchy product` (<< *does this make any sense?*):

> 1 : 81 = 1 / 9  x  1 / 9 = 0,111....x  0,111.... = 0,0(1)(1+1)(1+1+1)(1+1+1+1)....etc
>
> = 0,123456789(10)(11)(12)(13)....( Cauchy product)

**Can somebody explain in layman's terms what's going on in this last step? Am I correct and can this be referred to as `base 9` counting?**

*(p.s.: my rep doesn't let me correctly tag this question)*

Comment: The infinite sum $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}r/10^{r+1}$ is equal to $1/81$. That's all there is to it.

Comment: The number is rational so at worst it is periodical. The number 0.123456789101112... is not.

Comment: @TonyK: can you explain what that means using words?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I see an irrational number following the sequence: 1234567891011121314. So in terms of clues, is this mathematical way of switching from one-dimensional `addition` to two-dimensional: `multiplication`?

Comment: @pqnet: I wish I could read those formulas as good as I can interpret visual representations....

Comment: @Ropstah this is something you will get used if you keep doing math. I guess you are still very young

Comment: I'm somewhere in my 3rd decade just lacking the ability to perform mathematical tasks. I understand practical implications of very complex concepts however my real mathematical education halted at the age of 17. Don't know if there is a practical path available for me which I can combine with my private life ;)

Comment: @Ropstah Depends on how much time you have left for hobby, and to which degree you are willing to play with maths as a hobby (or more than a hoppy, by the way). For any specific mathematical subject that may be of interest to you, there are many good books, at any level. You'll have to give hints on what you want to do and maybe ask for references in another question.

Comment: I'd like to define quantum thermodynamics (gravity in other words). Just joking, my hobby is really just science. I'm trying to catch up on everything I couldn't mentally get a grasp on at school. Getting very high grades for math, physics and biology led me to quantum physics (which wasn't really mainstream in my age) and everything being a hobby sometimes gives me the opportunity to choose where I want to go deeper. I hope this doesn't feel like wasted time and hope everybody enjoys it. I really appreciate all comments and just hope it leads to alternative ways of gaining knowledge.

Comment: @Ropstah I'm rather surprised that you followed a QP curriculum without mathematics beyond age 17. Surprised is an understatement. Nevertheles, it's up to you to tell what you want, I can't give you any book advice without any hint from you. If you have a good library nearby, you should go there and have a look.

Comment: Visualization is key. I never did well with books or using theory as a starting point. However I found out that the theory isn't what defines practice. It's the practice which forms the theory...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because when you do $0.00000008 +0.000000009 + 0.0000000010 + 0.00000000011$ *carry rules* apply and it becomes $0.0000000901...$

\begin{align}
0&.01 &+\\
0&.002 &+\\
0&.0003 &+\\
0&.00004 &+\\
0&.000005 &+\\
0&.0000006 &+\\
0&.00000007 &+\\
0&.000000008 &+\\
0&.0000000009 &+\\
0&.00000000010 &+\\
0&.000000000011 &+\\
0&.0000000000012 &=\\
0&.0123456790122
\end{align}

**Edit:** $\frac1{81}$ is a rational number, thus it has a periodic representation in base 10. It can be easily verified that
$$\frac1{81} = \frac{12345679}{999999999} = 0.\overline{012345679}$$
so $8$ never appears in the decimal expansion of $\frac1{81}$

Comment: It will get even worse when you have over $100$ terms.  Then you carry into two places, and so on.

Comment: @RossMillikan I didn't want to write 100 digit numbers just to show them: I confided reader would be able to figure out on its own.

Comment: I agree, but I think it is easier to figure out with that added.

Comment: @pgnet: you're right. This visualization helps me enough to get it right in my head. I'll try to get this programmed and upload the 100 term result somewhere for others to enjoy. Does this make any sense by the way: `x = reciproc(sqrt(reciproc(x^2)))` I'm afraid to ask this in another question?

Comment: @Ropstah Be careful that the usual computer floating point numbers cannot represent correctly 100 decimal digits. I don't understand the point in `x = reciproc(sqrt(reciproc(x^2)))`

Comment: I was aware of the limitations, I hope some math library will help me out there. Regarding that function, I understand it just says `x=x`? In my question I was referring to `base 9`. I'm trying to figure out how multiplication and reciprocity work in base 9. I'm having a hard time bringing this to words and thought that function might have something in it...

Comment: base 9 works the same as base 10, just carry happens more often

Comment: Ok (hope you can bear with me), so I transposed (at least tried to) the reciprocal of 81 to base 9, giving `0.00888888888...`. Is this correct?

Comment: in base 9 `0.00888888888...` is the same as `0.01`, so it is correct. When using base 10 powers of 10 are represented with only 1 digit equal to 1 all others being zero, in base 9 that happens for powers of nine, that is: $10_9 = 9$, $100_9 = 81$ $1000_9 = 729$. Same for decimal numbers: $0.1_9 = 1/9$ and $0.01_9 = 1/81$.

Comment: Fair enough! Is there a last light which you can shine on me today? Why are `base 3` (0.000022222222...) and `base 9` representations so 'simple'?

Comment: because $81 = 9\times9 = 3\times3\times3\times3$ is a power of both 3 and 9. Same reason 1/100 representation in base 10 is simple. Note that in base 3 a periodic 2 is actually a 1 on the last non-periodic number (`0.000022222222...` is the same as `0.0001`)

Comment: Sorry to keep commenting :) but is there anything you can say about the `base 6` representation (`0.002345`). I'm unable to calculate this one any further but suspect there might be an 'appealing' sequence. However I cannot relate your powering to `6` in finding 81 (81 = 9^2 = 3^4)...

Comment: $6= 3 \times 2$ thus $6^4 = 3^4\times 2^4 = 81 \times 16$ hence $\frac1{81} = 16 \times \frac1{6^4} = 24_6 \times 0.0001_6 = 0.0024_6$. Your result is a bit off. Generally, a fraction $\frac1n$ has a finite representation in a base $b$ if the prime factors of $n$ are the same as the prime factors in $b$. This is true for base ten too: the only case in which there is a finite representation of a number $\frac1n$ in base 10 is when $n= 2^a \times 5^b$ for some values of $a$ and $b$

Comment: I cheated and made the sequence 0.002345 where it should've been 0.002344444... something. Don't know why... haha. Anyway thanks a lot! Really appreciate your comments.

Comment: Your edit confuses me. You suddenly made the number rational. Where did `0.0123456789101112...` go to? :)

Comment: @Ropstah every fraction is rational, by the same definition of rational number. It is true that $\frac1{81} = 0.1 \times 0 + 0.01\times 1 + 0.001\times 2 + 0.0001\times 3 + 0.00001\times 4$ but I already showed you that because of carry rules the result of that computation will never be `0.0123456789101112...`

Comment: I misread the definition of rational numbers as if they needed to be countable. Are you as a mathematician aware of this 'fact' and that this is related to the prime reciprocal magic square? Funny how the prime number in **base 3** always seems to be higher then the total of the sum of diagonal values... ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_reciprocal_magic_square

Comment: Countable means that there is a way to enumerate them (and it is true for rational number). It has no relation to the decimal expansion of a number itself. "Prime reciprocal magic square" is off-topic: this is not a chat website, if a question is not specific enough it will be closed.

Comment: Got it, i was getting a bit over enthusiastic. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This is really just a comment, but I didn't want you to miss it:

**Stay away from that site! It will rot your brain!**

Just about every sentence is false. There aren't many crank sites you can say that about, but this is one of them.

Comment: Hahahahah, I really appreciate this comment. I didn't have any intentions whatsoever to deepen my relations with that site from that perspective.

Comment: A true mathematician doesn't care about the source of a piece of information to decide whether to trust it or not, but she will deem it trustful only when she can proof its validity herself. It is not sufficient to be convinced that some piece of information is true or false, a mathematician has to be able to prove _why_ it is true or false, otherwise she will just say "I don't know", no matter whether the source is a bogus site or a scientific paper or even a textbook.

Comment: +1 just to pique my curiosity to check out that ... interesting ... site.

Comment: @pqnet: On that basis, true mathematicians became extinct about 150 years ago. That is not something to be mourned; it just means that the whole world can know more than any one person in it. BTW: Are you serious?

Comment: Maybe current literature is not as efficient as it could be?

Comment: @TonyK there is no knowledge in mathematics beside axioms. Everything else is derived from them. Actually from a logical point of view, if a proof uses lemmas without proving them, it is a proof that if the lemmas used hold the theorem is true. This is actually something that does not require the reader to be able to prove everything that stands behind a theorem, because the theorem has a meaning on its own (well, if some of the assumption are provably false it is not much interesting though)

Comment: @pqnet: That seems to me to be a far more reasonable viewpoint than your earlier comment.

Comment: @TonyK The two statements are the same from my point of view. Assuming `A` being true to prove `B` is equivalent as proving the theorem `if A then B`. Note that `if A then B` can be proven even if `A` is not true (and it is actually pretty simple in that case)